# Mass Update Magento Field to "Use Default Value"

Tags: magento, import, magento-1.4, product

Is there a way that I can reset a bunch of magento products for a particular store view back to "Use Default Value"  It seems once you set the store specific data there is no easy way to unset so that it receives the default data.  This is causing me to have to do multiple imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove record from product_entity_[attirubte_type] for the product_id, attribute_id and store_id.

Comment: Thanks, yes the table was mage_catalog_product_entity_decimal for pricing

Comment: As of 1.5 "catalog_product_entity_[attirubte_type]", attirubte_type is reference to the data type varchar,text, decimal etc

Comment: Worked perfectly, however, even after removing every single record where store_id != 0 from every product_entity_* table, new records where store_id != 0 keeps being recreated. Its very strange because 1) it sometimes happen even when no one has updated a product via admin 2) when created, the records will replicate changes from the record where store_id = 0, however, not always, it seems random. 3) this is a headache, because even after removing all the non-storeid = 0 records, when i update products in the default store view, the 'use default value' checkbox keeps unchecking... any clues?

Answer (score 6):

I know you want to change "a bunch of products" ... 
Just for the usecase someone want to **get rid of the store-view-specific values for ALL products**:
Just cycle the scope of the attribute from 'Store View' to 'Global' an back to 'Store View' again.

Comment: That's interesting to know.. but for my case it was only for certain stores, not for all stores.

Comment: I know. It was a note for random guys passing by searching for an ALL STORE solution. Sorry for hijacking your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` `adminhtml` event to add the required checkboxes for every attribute in admin mass update form;
- then `catalog_product_attribute_update_before` event to delete the values from the `EAV` tables for a specific store view, only for those attributes that have the checkbox you injected earlier with `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` set as checked.

Original answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/45229/16724